# RegEx Pattern matching allows for period

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex

I am using a `CLR` assembly for `RegEx` pattern matching in SQL.  The assembly I have is very simple.  The pattern I am attempting to find errant data to does not allow for periods, I believe.  However, the data which contains periods in it, is not being returned by the `CLR-based UDF`.

I know one solution to find the invalid data may be to update the pattern, however, the patterns are from a third-party XML Schema and thus I cannot change the pattern I am using.

I have been using http://regexr.com/ as a means to validate what characters should and should not be picked up by the pattern.  In the scenario below, the period character is not valid by the pattern when using the website.

Am I missing something with my implementation?

---

**String Data:** `TEST. DATA`

**Pattern Being Matched:** `'([A-Za-z] ?)*[A-Za-z]'`

**RegEx CLR Class Method:**

```
[SqlFunction(IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
public static bool RegExMatch(string pattern, string matchString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(matchString) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(pattern))
        return false;

    Regex r1 = new Regex(pattern.TrimEnd(null));
    return r1.Match(matchString.TrimEnd(null)).Success;
}
```

**Test SQL Code:**

```
SELECT 'TEST. DATA' AS TEST_STRING
      , dbo.RegExMatch('([A-Za-z] ?)*[A-Za-z]', 'TEST. DATA') AS PatternMatch
```

Comment: This pattern really only asserts that the input text ends with an alphabetic character. If you put `...a` into the website, it will show a successful match. If you can't update the Regex pattern, I'm not sure what to suggest. Adding anchors to the pattern would help, with some nuance around whether you are doing multiline matching. `^[ A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z]$`

Comment: If you get user-defined regexps and want to match the *entire string*, you need to wrap them with not only anchors, but an outer grouping. Try `dbo.RegExMatch(CONCAT('^(?:', '([A-Za-z] ?)*[A-Za-z]',')$'), 'TEST. DATA')`. If a regex contains alternation operator, it would be ruined otherwise.

Comment: The [Success](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.success(v=vs.110).aspx) property returns `true` if it found any match, and according to [this](https://regex101.com/r/7dXE9j/1) you have 2 matches. It's hard to say how to work around this considering you can't change the pattern. I think you need to define more precisely what it is you are "validating", as the 3rd party regex pattern you are being handed is not enough to simply match against for true/false validation.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that the *patterns are from a third-party XML Schema*. The regex flavor is very similar to .NET, so it is possible that all of them will work well in .NET. However, **all the XML Schema patterns are anchored by default**, that regex flavor does not support `^` and `$` as start-of-string and end-of-string anchors.

That means, you need to add anchors to the regexps you test, `^`/`\A` to match at the start of the string, and `$`/`\z` to match the end of the string (`\z` is preferable).

The safest way to add this support, is via enclosing the pattern with `^(?:` and `)$`.

Comment: Enclosing the test pattern with what you describe is now failing the `TEST. DATA` string validation, so that appears to be working.  In your experience, would you say that manually enclosing the pattern as you describe does not alter the actual test patter, but makes it more valid to be tested against?

Comment: No, this outer grouping is a valid approach, also used in the default anchoring of regexps inside [HTML5 `pattern` attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-pattern-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern of the subjects resembles TEST. DATA a pattern like this should work.

```
^([A-Za-z]+)(\.)?\s?([A-Za-z]+)$
```

Currently the pattern must start with at least 1 letter followed by 0 or 1 periods followed by 1 or more space characters followed by 1 or more letters.

EDIT: Just read the second paragraph of your question and noticed you cannot change the pattern.

Comment: PS. You can swap out the $ for \z if you do not want to match a newline character at the end of the string